# How to identify ions by their quantum number?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

If the quantum numbers of an ion are given, how can we identify this ion by its quantum numbers?

For example :

> n = 3; $l$ = 2; $m_l$ = 0; m$_s$ = + ½

What I have so far: $n$ is 3 and $l$ is 2 which corresponds to $d$, so the last shell is $3d1$, therefore we have 21 $e^-$ and the answer will be $\ce{Sc}$ ion (from the periodic table) and the answer I got is $\ce{Mn^{2+}}$.   Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Please show how you arrived at Mn+.  As I mentioned on your other question, it's critical that you put forth more effort towards these problems.

Comment: Why !! at the end of each chapter in the book there are a lot of problems .. some of them, their answers are at the end of the book .. but only the final answer is there .. So, I took one of the solved questions that I dont understand and I put it here because i have no idea how to start solving it.. consequently, how do you expect me to show some effort about something that I don't know the way it is solved ?

Comment: it is better to know : I am not scientist and my major has nothing to do with chemistry, but it is a general course that I have to take .. it is hard enough.. don't make it more ! at least write down some guidelines that I should follow to show some effort :(

Comment: Maher - start by explaining what you do understand. You must know something - even if it doesn't seem like it will help. That way we have a better idea of where to start. For example, think about the quantum numbers - what do they refer to? Is it a whole atom? All the electrons? Some of the electrons? If we know what you do understand, it is a lot easier to fill in the gaps. Otherwise, we are left with trying to give an introductory quantum chemistry lecture in the space of one answer.

Comment: you don't need to give introductory because I have it, once you give the way of solution even without explaining it I will know it directly. anyway: n is 3 and l is 2 which corresponds to d .. so the last shell is $3d^1$ .. therefore we have 21e and the answer will be Sc ion ( from periodic table) ? and ( the correct answer is $Mn^{2+}$ ) ???..

Comment: @Maher The point is that from your lectures or your text, you know something towards solving the problem (as you have demonstrated with the previous comment).  Just include that in the body of the question and there will be no problem.  It doesn't matter if you are a chemistry major or an English major, we enacted this rule to keep things fair and to keep this site from deteriorating into a homework service.

Comment: I have given you the proper framework for what we expect from those asking questions based on the information given in your comment.  Please follow this from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pattern-based approach: Remember that the values for ${m_l}$ are centered about 0. This means for a d-orbital, where ${l=2}$, the values of ${m_l}$ = ${(-2, -1, 0, +1, +2)}$.

So, for ${l=2}$ and ${m_l=0}$ and ${m_s=+1/2}$, you should arrive at ${d^3}$. The orbitals each get an electron for all the positive spins first, then are filled completely with the negative spin ones.

That means you "visit" ${m_l}$ twice (in rising order: -2, -1, 0, +1, +2, repeat).

This means the first d-electron (↑ _ _ _ _) such as ${Sc}$ has the configuration ${m_l=-2, m_s=+1/2.}$

The 3rd electron (↑ ↑ ↑ _ _) would have ${m_l=0, m_s=+1/2}$.

A 5-electron configuration (↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑) would have ${m_l=+2, m_s=+1/2}$.

Now on the right-hand side of the d-group, the 6th electron (↑↓ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑) would have ${m_l=-2, m_s=-1/2}$, and then the magnetic quantum numbers rise to +2 again at ${d10}$.

Anyways, ${Mn^{+2}}$ is ${d^{3}}$ (5 to start, then subtract 2 because of its +2 charge) which matches the quantum numbers you specified.

It's not an 8 electron configuration because of the spin specified. That'd be (↑↓ ↑↓ ↑↓ ↑ ↑).